# javax mail Imap Content-Transfer-Encoding

Tags: java, email, imap

I've using javax mail api to read messages on imap server.
I check message content-transfer-encoding, because I do mime decoding if I have to.

Recently, I encountered a problem: My code does not find any content-transfer-encoding on message. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's all in [RFC 1521](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/5.htm), I won't repeat that here. However, I have a feeling that you want to read `Content-Type` rather than `content-transfer-encoding` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If c-t-e isn't present the c-t-e is binary (which is the same as 8bit and 7bit) and decoding is eeeasy.